# Optimized method for calculating cosine distance in Python

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, distance

I wrote a method to calculate the cosine distance between two arrays:

```
def cosine_distance(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    numerator = 0
    denoma = 0
    denomb = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        numerator += a[i]*b[i]
        denoma += abs(a[i])**2
        denomb += abs(b[i])**2
    result = 1 - numerator / (sqrt(denoma)*sqrt(denomb))
    return result
```

Running it can be very slow on a large array. Is there an optimized version of this method that would run faster?

Update: I've tried all the suggestions to date, including scipy. Here's the version to beat, incorporating suggestions from Mike and Steve:

```
def cosine_distance(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        raise ValueError, "a and b must be same length" #Steve
    numerator = 0
    denoma = 0
    denomb = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):       #Mike's optimizations:
        ai = a[i]             #only calculate once
        bi = b[i]
        numerator += ai*bi    #faster than exponent (barely)
        denoma += ai*ai       #strip abs() since it's squaring
        denomb += bi*bi
    result = 1 - numerator / (sqrt(denoma)*sqrt(denomb))
    return result
```

Comment: Are a and b arrays of complex numbers?

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions so far, and currently Mike Dunlavey's suggestions of streamlining the existing code have given the best results. I guess I'll leave the question open in case there are other strategies of dealing with the issue, but most of the suggestions ended up actually running slower than the original code, so Python must do a pretty good job optimizing on the fly. And @gnibbler, I'm not using any complex numbers.

Comment: I don't understand why you take the abs before you square then.

Comment: For large arrays numpy should become much faster than looping in Python. Can you post the data you are testing with?

Comment: Here's what I'm using to test:

for i in range(1000000):
 a = cosine_distance([2,3,1],[2,3,6])

Comment: I just ran a quick test, using numpy was faster when the lists are around 1000 elements.

Comment: The reason the numpy is slower for small arrays is because of the overhead of the conversion to numpy arrays.

Comment: No problem, there is probably a crossover point where the pure python versions using sum will be faster than the for loop also, so you really need to test with your typical data (large means different things to different people)

Comment: As long as you are trying things to shave the code, you might try using `xrange()` instead of `range()` if you are still on Python 2.x.  If you are on Python 3, then there is only `range()` and it returns an iterator.

Comment: If your whole project was in SciPy, and you didn't have to convert to a NumPy array because `a` and `b` were already NumPy arrays, then I expect the SciPy function would be a clear winner.

Comment: I just timed your current version, versus your version modified to use `xrange()`.  As I expected, `xrange()` is the tiniest whisker faster, because it avoids the need to allocate and free the memory for the list of `int` values; in my test it was about 0.2% faster for lists of length 5000.

Comment: With the change to `xrange()` I am out of ideas; I think you have found the fastest version possible in plain Python.  If you really need more speed, switch your whole project to SciPy, or else write a custom C module, perhaps via Cython: http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html

Comment: Whoops, I spoke too soon.  I just ran some tests.  The clear winner was Darius Bacon's function that uses `izip()`.  He apologized, saying "It's ugly, but it does come out faster..."  Well, I don't think it's *that* ugly and it is the clear winner for speed.  It makes sense: the `range()` solution involves indexing into each list twice to lookup values, and allocating and deallocating a list; the `xrange()` solution involves indexing into each list twice for lookup, and running an iterator; the `izip()` solution uses an iterator to fetch each item once, which just has to be faster!

Comment: I just reran my tests, including gnibbler's answer, and simply using `from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine`.  For lists of length 500,000 the `cosine` function from SciPy is the clear winner, with gnibbler's answer almost as fast.  For lists of length 3, Darius Bacon's `izip()` function is the clear winner, and the SciPy and NumPy based solutions are so bad they are outliers.  Which suggests the ultimate solution!  See my new answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use SciPy, you can use `cosine` from `spatial.distance`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

If you can't use SciPy, you could try to obtain a small speedup by rewriting your Python (EDIT: but it didn't work out like I thought it would, see below).

```
from itertools import izip
from math import sqrt

def cosine_distance(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        raise ValueError, "a and b must be same length"
    numerator = sum(tup[0] * tup[1] for tup in izip(a,b))
    denoma = sum(avalue ** 2 for avalue in a)
    denomb = sum(bvalue ** 2 for bvalue in b)
    result = 1 - numerator / (sqrt(denoma)*sqrt(denomb))
    return result
```

It is better to raise an exception when the lengths of a and b are mismatched.

By using generator expressions inside of calls to `sum()` you can calculate your values with most of the work being done by the C code inside of Python.  This should be faster than using a `for` loop.

I haven't timed this so I can't guess how much faster it might be.  But the SciPy code is almost certainly written in C or C++ and it should be about as fast as you can get.

If you are doing bioinformatics in Python, you really should be using SciPy anyway.

EDIT: Darius Bacon timed my code and found it slower.  So I timed my code and... yes, it is slower.  The lesson for all: when you are trying to speed things up, don't guess, measure.

I am baffled as to why my attempt to put more work on the C internals of Python is slower.  I tried it for lists of length 1000 and it was still slower.

I can't spend any more time on trying to hack the Python cleverly.  If you need more speed, I suggest you try SciPy.

EDIT: I just tested by hand, without timeit.  I find that for short a and b, the old code is faster; for long a and b, the new code is faster; in both cases the difference is not large.  (I'm now wondering if I can trust timeit on my Windows computer; I want to try this test again on Linux.)  I wouldn't change working code to try to get it faster.  And one more time I urge you to try SciPy.  :-)

Comment: The numerator line is incorrect: it does a nested loop instead of a parallel one.

Comment: Also, when I fixed that line to get the right answer, it's still slower than the original code. Agreed about SciPy anyway!

(numerator = sum(avalue * bvalue for avalue, bvalue in zip(a, b)))

Comment: Good call with SciPy. Unfortunately your non-SciPy rewrite returns the wrong values. Replacing the numerator line with gnibbler's results in the right answer, but it's actually much slower than my original code.

Comment: Interestingly, scipy was actually much slower. For testing I ran a couple small arrays through 100K iterations. Original code ran ~1.3 seconds and scipy ran at ~7.5 seconds. I wonder if the tables would turn on larger arrays?

Comment: Out of curiosity, since I don't have SciPy installed but am perpetually intrigued by the project, have you got any timing for this particular case using cosine from spatial.distance?

Comment: Thanks Steve—I'll give it a shot on the production code, which will have much larger arrays.

Comment: `scipy.spatial.distance` is incredibly slow. That's not surprising: It is [just a normal python function](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/d69a5f3ec58a57610d0829b19490b7de7fdfed52/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L267) :(

Answer (score 6):

(I originally thought) you're not going to speed it up a lot without breaking out to C (like numpy or scipy) or changing what you compute. But here's how I'd try that, anyway:

```
from itertools import imap
from math import sqrt
from operator import mul

def cosine_distance(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    return 1 - (sum(imap(mul, a, b))
                / sqrt(sum(imap(mul, a, a))
                       * sum(imap(mul, b, b))))
```

It's roughly twice as fast in Python 2.6 with 500k-element arrays. (After changing map to imap, following Jarret Hardie.)

Here's a tweaked version of the original poster's revised code:

```
from itertools import izip

def cosine_distance(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    ab_sum, a_sum, b_sum = 0, 0, 0
    for ai, bi in izip(a, b):
        ab_sum += ai * bi
        a_sum += ai * ai
        b_sum += bi * bi
    return 1 - ab_sum / sqrt(a_sum * b_sum)
```

It's ugly, but it does come out faster. . .

**Edit:** And try [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/)! It speeds up the final version by another factor of 4. How could I forget?

Comment: nice addition - glad to hear that the use of imap offers an advantage to mul over ** 2

Comment: I don't think it's that ugly :p

Comment: I was just a bit chagrined to see the imperative code beating out the purely functional code that more directly expresses the problem.

Answer (score 2):

No need to take `abs()` of `a[i]` and `b[i]` if you're squaring it.

Store `a[i]` and `b[i]` in temporary variables, to avoid doing the indexing more than once.
Maybe the compiler can optimize this, but maybe not.

Check into the `**2` operator. Is it simplifying it into a multiply, or is it using a general power function (log - multiply by 2 - antilog).

Don't do sqrt twice (though the cost of that is small). Do `sqrt(denoma * denomb)`.

Comment: Good call... each of these shaved off a bit of time.

Comment: @Dan: Welcome. Next I'd see if some unrolling would help, in case the iterator is costing you (they tend to do that). Next I would do some stack sampling to see if the function is being called any more than necessary (or if there is any other unnoticed time-tumor).

Answer (score 1):

This is faster for arrays of around 1000+ elements.

```
from numpy import array
def cosine_distance(a, b):
    a=array(a)
    b=array(b)
    numerator=(a*b).sum()
    denoma=(a*a).sum()
    denomb=(b*b).sum()
    result = 1 - numerator / sqrt(denoma*denomb)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Darius Bacon's answer, I've been toying with operator and itertools to produce a faster answer. The following seems to be 1/3 faster on a 500-item array according to timeit:

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import imap
from operator import mul

def op_cosine(a, b):
    dot_prod = sum(imap(mul, a, b))
    a_veclen = sqrt(sum(i ** 2 for i in a))
    b_veclen = sqrt(sum(i ** 2 for i in b))

    return 1 - dot_prod / (a_veclen * b_veclen)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the C code inside of SciPy wins big for long input arrays.  Using simple and direct Python wins for short input arrays; Darius Bacon's `izip()`-based code benchmarked out best.  Thus, the ultimate solution is to decide which one to use at runtime, based on the length of the input arrays:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine as scipy_cos_dist

from itertools import izip
from math import sqrt

def cosine_distance(a, b):
    len_a = len(a)
    assert len_a == len(b)
    if len_a > 200:  # 200 is a magic value found by benchmark
        return scipy_cos_dist(a, b)
    # function below is basically just Darius Bacon's code
    ab_sum = a_sum = b_sum = 0
    for ai, bi in izip(a, b):
        ab_sum += ai * bi
        a_sum += ai * ai
        b_sum += bi * bi
    return 1 - ab_sum / sqrt(a_sum * b_sum)
```

I made a test harness that tested the functions with different length inputs, and found that around length 200 the SciPy function started to win.  The bigger the input arrays, the bigger it wins.  For very short length arrays, say length 3, the simpler code wins.  This function adds a tiny amount of overhead to decide which way to do it, then does it the best way.

In case you are interested, here is the test harness:

```
from darius2 import cosine_distance as fn_darius2
fn_darius2.__name__ = "fn_darius2"

from ult import cosine_distance as fn_ult
fn_ult.__name__ = "fn_ult"

from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine as fn_scipy
fn_scipy.__name__ = "fn_scipy"

import random
import time

lst_fn = [fn_darius2, fn_scipy, fn_ult]

def run_test(fn, lst0, lst1, test_len):
    start = time.time()
    for _ in xrange(test_len):
        fn(lst0, lst1)
    end = time.time()
    return end - start

for data_len in range(50, 500, 10):
    a = [random.random() for _ in xrange(data_len)]
    b = [random.random() for _ in xrange(data_len)]
    print "len(a) ==", len(a)
    test_len = 10**3
    for fn in lst_fn:
        n = fn.__name__
        r = fn(a, b)
        t = run_test(fn, a, b, test_len)
        print "%s:\t%f seconds, result %f" % (n, t, r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cd(a,b):
    if(len(a)!=len(b)):
        raise ValueError, "a and b must be the same length"
    rn = range(len(a))
    adb = sum([a[k]*b[k] for k in rn])
    nma = sqrt(sum([a[k]*a[k] for k in rn]))
    nmb = sqrt(sum([b[k]*b[k] for k in rn]))

    result = 1 - adb / (nma*nmb)
    return result
```

Comment: You are using list comprehensions inside of calls to `sum()`.  This will create a list, then `sum()` will use the list once, and then the list will be garbage-collected.  Python has a nifty feature called "generator expressions" where you can use the same syntax as a list comprehension, but it will create an iterator.  If you simply delete the `[` and `]` from inside your calls to `sum()`, you will now be using generator expressions.  Read more about this here: http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions

Comment: @steveha: depends on input lenght and the function. I don't know here, but str.join(..) is faster with list comprehensions than genexps for short input (len ~100).

Comment: @kaizer.se: `str.join` is a special case, since when it has a list, it first sums the lens, then it creates a string of total size and fills it with the parts; otherwise, it builds the string the obvious way (for part in iterable: result+= part)

Answer (score 0):

Your updated solution still has two square roots. You can reduce this to one by replacing the sqrt line with:

> result = 1 - numerator /
>   (sqrt(denoma*denomb))

A multiply is typically quite a bit quicker than a sqrt. It might not seem much as it is only called once in the function, but it sounds like you are calculating a lot of cosine distances, so the improvement will add up.

Your code looks like it should be ripe for vector optimizations. So if cross-platofrm support is not an issue and you want to speed it even further, you could code the cosine distance code in C and make sure your compiler is aggressively vectorizing the resulting code (even Pentium II is capable of some floating point vectorisation)