# Optimized dot product in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math

The dot product of two n-dimensional vectors `u=[u1,u2,...un]` and `v=[v1,v2,...,vn]` is is given by `u1*v1 + u2*v2 + ... + un*vn`.

A question [posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823293/optimized-method-for-calculating-cosine-distance-in-python/1823735#1823735) encouraged me to find the fastest way to compute dot products in Python using only the standard library, no third-party modules or C/Fortran/C++ calls.

I timed four different approaches; so far the fastest seems to be `sum(starmap(mul,izip(v1,v2)))` (where `starmap` and `izip` come from the `itertools` module).

For the code presented below, these are the elapsed times (in seconds, for one million runs):

```
d0: 12.01215
d1: 11.76151
d2: 12.54092
d3: 09.58523
```

Can you think of a faster way to do this?

```
import timeit # module with timing subroutines                                                              
import random # module to generate random numnbers                                                          
from itertools import imap,starmap,izip
from operator import mul

def v(N=50,min=-10,max=10):
    """Generates a random vector (in an array) of dimension N; the                                          
    values are integers in the range [min,max]."""
    out = []
    for k in range(N):
        out.append(random.randint(min,max))
    return out

def check(v1,v2):
    if len(v1)!=len(v2):
        raise ValueError,"the lenght of both arrays must be the same"
    pass

def d0(v1,v2):
    """                                                                                                     
    d0 is Nominal approach:                                                                                 
    multiply/add in a loop                                                                                  
    """
    check(v1,v2)
    out = 0
    for k in range(len(v1)):
        out += v1[k] * v2[k]
    return out

def d1(v1,v2):
    """                                                                                                     
    d1 uses an imap (from itertools)                                                                        
    """
    check(v1,v2)
    return sum(imap(mul,v1,v2))

def d2(v1,v2):
    """                                                                                                     
    d2 uses a conventional map                                                                              
    """
    check(v1,v2)
    return sum(map(mul,v1,v2))

def d3(v1,v2):
    """                                                                                                     
    d3 uses a starmap (itertools) to apply the mul operator on an izipped (v1,v2)                           
    """
    check(v1,v2)
    return sum(starmap(mul,izip(v1,v2)))

# generate the test vectors                                                                                 
v1 = v()
v2 = v()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Generate two test vectors of dimension N                                                              

    t0 = timeit.Timer("d0(v1,v2)","from dot_product import d0,v1,v2")
    t1 = timeit.Timer("d1(v1,v2)","from dot_product import d1,v1,v2")
    t2 = timeit.Timer("d2(v1,v2)","from dot_product import d2,v1,v2")
    t3 = timeit.Timer("d3(v1,v2)","from dot_product import d3,v1,v2")

    print "d0 elapsed: ", t0.timeit()
    print "d1 elapsed: ", t1.timeit()
    print "d2 elapsed: ", t2.timeit()
    print "d3 elapsed: ", t3.timeit()
```

Notice that the name of the file must be `dot_product.py` for the script to run; I used Python 2.5.1 on a Mac OS X Version 10.5.8.

EDIT:

I ran the script for N=1000 and these are the results (in seconds, for one million runs):

```
d0: 205.35457
d1: 208.13006
d2: 230.07463
d3: 155.29670
```

I guess it is safe to assume that, indeed, option three is the fastest and option two the slowest (of the four presented).

Comment: @Arrieta: You can remove the requirement that the file be called dot_product.py by replacing 'from dot_product' with 'from __main__'.

Comment: @unutbu: Sure, I just think it is simpler to save the file with that name for a quick run than it is to alter the script. Thank you.

Comment: My results are:
d0 elapsed:  13.4328830242
d1 elapsed:  9.52215504646
d2 elapsed:  10.1050257683
d3 elapsed:  9.16764998436
Be sure to check if the differences between d1 and d3 are statistically significant.

Comment: @liori: Exactly. I am running the problem for N=1000 and will expect to see a greater difference.

Comment: If you're doing a dot product repeatedly, holding one of the vectors constant, a dynamic compilation approach may be worth investigating. All the terms where the fixed part is 0 can be removed entirely, and the multiplication can be eliminated if the fixed part is 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for fun I wrote a "d4" which uses numpy:

```
from numpy import dot
def d4(v1, v2): 
    check(v1, v2)
    return dot(v1, v2)
```

My results (Python 2.5.1, XP Pro sp3, 2GHz Core2 Duo T7200):

```
d0 elapsed:  12.1977242918
d1 elapsed:  13.885232341
d2 elapsed:  13.7929552499
d3 elapsed:  11.0952246724
```

<strike>d4 elapsed:  56.3278584289   # go numpy!</strike>

And, for even more fun, I turned on psyco:

```
d0 elapsed:  0.965477735299
d1 elapsed:  12.5354792299
d2 elapsed:  12.9748163524
d3 elapsed:  9.78255448667
```

<strike>d4 elapsed:  54.4599059378</strike>

Based on that, I declare d0 the winner :)

---

**Update**

@kaiser.se: I probably should have mentioned that I did convert everything to numpy arrays first:

```
from numpy import array
v3 = [array(vec) for vec in v1]
v4 = [array(vec) for vec in v2]

# then
t4 = timeit.Timer("d4(v3,v4)","from dot_product import d4,v3,v4")
```

And I included `check(v1, v2)` since it's included in the other tests. Leaving it off would give numpy an unfair advantage (though it looks like it could use one). The array conversion shaved off about a second (much less than I thought it would).

All of my tests were run with N=50.

@nikow: I'm using numpy 1.0.4, which is undoubtedly old, it's certainly possible that they've improved performance over the last year and a half since I've installed it.

---

**Update #2**

@kaiser.se Wow, you are totally right. I must have been thinking that these were lists of lists or something (I really have no idea what I was thinking ... +1 for pair programming).

How does this look:

```
v3 = array(v1)
v4 = array(v2)
```

New results:

```
d4 elapsed:  3.22535741274
```

With Psyco:

```
d4 elapsed:  2.09182619579
```

d0 still wins with Psyco, but numpy is probably better overall, especially with larger data sets.

Yesterday I was a bit bothered my slow numpy result, since presumably numpy is used for *a lot* of computation and has had a lot of optimization. Obviously though, not bothered enough to check my result :)

Comment: Great findings, Seth! First, it is incredible that Numpy is so slow! I would expect it to be much faster. Also, I had no clue about Psyco (and I considered myself a Python junkie!) - thanks for pointing it out, I will definitively check it out. Finally, it is interesting to see that, basically, the Psyco thing made pure optimized C code for d0 and did not know how to optimize d3. I guess the message is that, if you want to use Psyco, you should lay out the algorithm so it can be optimized (as opposed to "hide" its logic behind Python constructs). Again, great findings!

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your numpy install. On my machine numpy is much faster than the other options (I didn't try psyco). And N=50 is a little small for numpy to show its strength.

Comment: you're doing it wrong. make numpy arrays once (instead of passing lists that will be converted by numpy *each time*), and numpy will be much faster. also drop the check.

Comment: you're doing it **extremely** wrong. You are passing a list to numpy. A list of single-element numpy arrays, in fact.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Just another example that it is hard to use numpy correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a comparison with numpy. We compare the fast starmap approach with `numpy.dot`

First, iteration over normal Python lists:

```
$ python -mtimeit "import numpy as np; r = range(100)" "np.dot(r,r)"
10 loops, best of 3: 316 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "import operator; r = range(100); from itertools import izip, starmap" "sum(starmap(operator.mul, izip(r,r)))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 81.5 usec per loop
```

Then numpy ndarray:

```
$ python -mtimeit "import numpy as np; r = np.arange(100)" "np.dot(r,r)"
10 loops, best of 3: 20.2 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit "import operator; import numpy as np; r = np.arange(100); from itertools import izip, starmap;" "sum(starmap(operator.mul, izip(r,r)))"
10 loops, best of 3: 405 usec per loop
```

Seeing this, it seems numpy on numpy arrays is fastest, followed by python functional constructs working with lists.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about faster, but I'd suggest:

```
sum(i*j for i, j in zip(v1, v2))
```

it's much easier to read and doesn't require even standard-library modules.

Comment: @SilentGhost: your approach takes much longer. For N=10 it took 18.0258 seconds (one million runs). What I am looking for is speed; indeed readability is a non-issue, since the dot product is called from a function (udotv=dot(u,v)), and I can comment the code as much as I need to in the definition of dot. Your approach really is not appropriate.

Comment: @SilentGhost, a quick ovservation:changing zip to itertools.izip reduces the time to 15.84879. Maybe worth knowing?

Comment: This is definitely what I would do. I throw in psyco for performance on Windows if that is an issue.

Comment: No Psyco: 18.6840143091. With Psyco: 25.0433867992. This must be one of those "worst case" optimizations for psyco for some reason. Using izip() (without psyco) only knocked it down to 17.4570938485.

Answer (score 0):

Please benchmark this "d2a" function, and compare it to your "d3" function.

```
from itertools import imap, starmap
from operator import mul

def d2a(v1,v2):
    """
    d2a uses itertools.imap
    """
    check(v1,v2)
    return sum(imap(mul, v1, v2))
```

`map` (on Python 2.x, which is what I assume you use) unnecessarily creates a dummy list prior to the computation.

Answer (score -2):

In Mathematica (10^12 additions and multiplications):

```
a = RandomReal[1,{10^4,10^4}];
b = RandomReal[1,{10^4,10^4}];
AbsoluteTiming[c=a.b;]//First
```

9.65295 seconds

(Windows 10, Dell XPS17 9700, Mathematica 12.3)

Comment: Your answer is not clear, there are some terms that need suporting information, please read: * [How do I write good a answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/31035768)