# Python 3.x list comprehension VS tuple generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, generator

Is there any reason for memory, speed or whatever, that I would want to use:

```
tuple(i for i in range(5000))
```

instead of:

```
[i for i in range(5000)]
```

If I didn't mind the immutability of tuples

Comment: Use the former if you need a tuple, use the latter (or `list(range(5000))`) if you need a list.

Comment: the choice between `tuple` or `list` is based on what you are planning on doing with it and not resources.

Comment: Apart from the overhead of the conversion, the tuple will be smaller and faster, since it lacks the mechanism to make it mutable, allow fast inserts etc. But the conversion of course costs extra time (once).

Comment: The first one will be slower, though it might take a bit less memory (in the end)

Comment: @EliKorvigo slower to construct?

Comment: For speed, you could remove the unneeded comprehension ;) `tuple(range(5000))` and `list(range(5000))`, or, depending on your needs, just `range(5000)`.

Comment: @new_to_coding yep

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically a list comprehension is faster than a generator expression and as the reason is that <strike>its iteration performs in C</strike>  (Read the @Veedrac's comment for the reason). But the only reason that should use a generator expression within tuple is that you want to perform some operations on your items and/or filter them and more importantly you want a tuple (because of the immutability and its benefits against mutable objects).

After all you can always `timeit` your code:

```
In [10]: %timeit tuple(i for i in range(5000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 325 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit [i for i in range(5000)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 199 µs per loop
```

Also note that as I mentioned, if you want to use comprehensions you must needed to perform an operation on your items otherwise you can call the function directly on your iterator, which is faster:

```
In [12]: %timeit list(range(5000))
10000 loops, best of 3: 98.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: "its iteration performs in C" → This is one of the most pervasive, utterly false myths about Python. The list comprehension is faster because suspending and resuming a function's frame is slow, not because there's anything particularly special about list comprehensions.

Comment: @Veedrac Do  you have any reliable resource for that? 'Cause, as far as I remember I've read that from Mark Lutz Learning python's book a long while ago. If it's not like so (which now that I think more probably you're right) not only that book but also other famous resources that might have mentioned this statement need a serious criticism.

Comment: I could walk you through the code that compiles this (I've even contributed to parts of it), but I can't find any reference on Google at the moment. I know they exist because I've written about this before, but my Google-fu is failing me.

Answer (score 2):

Generator expressions (or *genexps*, for short) are best used in loops to save memory when handling a lot of data.  It's not considered good practice to expand a genexp to an interable data type (such as a list, tuple, set).

Also keep in mind that range() in Python 3 is like xrange() in Python 2.  It returns a generator.  In fact, xrange() tends to be faster even for 5000.  Note: xrange() does not exist in Python 3.