# Pythonic way for calculating

Tags: python

I have two python lists of floats (lists are of same size i.e same number of elements)

```
list1 = [20, 30, 40, 50]
list2 = [1.1, 1.3, 1.7, 1.8]
```

I want to calculate `sum(list1[i]*list2[i])/sum(list1[i])` (where i goes from 0 to len(list1).

This can be done using for loop, but is there a better way (more pythonic way like using lambda etc..)

Thanks

Comment: Lambda isn't Pythonic. Guido doesn't like it. Also, why do you have `sum(list[i])`? Do you want the sum of the list *up to* i?

Comment: @Rafe - that's debatable argument.

Comment: This is called the [weighted mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean), btw.

Comment: @user424060 Could you at least answer to the question of Rafe Kettler, please. As presently stated, your question can't be understood without estimating interpretation, particularly  because of the presence of **i** in ``/sum(list1[i])`` that makes it unclear. The value of ``sum(list1[i])`` is simply ``list1[i]``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about more Pythonic (simple is better, right?) but for something more concise, how about:

```
sum(a * b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)) / sum(list1)
```

This is largely adapted from [another answer by SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828233/optimized-dot-product-in-python/1828462#1828462).

The first part of what you are doing (up to the division) is called the dot product, by the way. If you have `numpy` installed, you can just do:

```
from numpy import dot
dot(list1, list2) / sum(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I would say that using lambda is "more pythonic," especially given the number of times that people have tried to reduce its power or remove it from the language.

There are a couple of ways you can do it. Zipping the lists so that you can use a list comprehension has been posted by a couple of people.  If you are looking for speed, [numpy](https://numpy.org/) has a dot product function. You can also do `sum([lst1[i] * lst2[i] for i in range(len(lst1))])` if you are looking for something more terse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

```
>>> sum(map(lambda i: i[0]*i[1],zip(list1,list2)))/sum(list1)
1.5642857142857143
```

Answer (score 0):

**[`List comprehension:`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**

```
>>> sum([ x*y for x,y in zip(list1,list2)])/sum(list1)
1.5642857142857143
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
sum(x*y for x, y in zip(list1, list2))/sum(list1)
```